# Strange 404 Errors in Search Console

Tags: google-search-console

I have a lot of 404 errors in my google's console with strange form.
some words added before a code which belong to another link.
for example, I have a post with these address

```
mysite.com/project-15155
mysite.com/project-16155
mysite.com/project-17155
```

In google's console, I have these 404s

```
mysite.com/master-xchange-project-15155
mysite.com/master-xchange-project-16155
mysite.com/master-xchange-project-17155
```

It is a WordPress site.
I also have checked "linked from" tab, but it could not useful!

Comment: "have checked "linked from" tab, but it could not useful!" - what do you mean "could not useful"? What is reported? (It looks like your site might have been hacked? ie. Google is seeing invalid URLs, but these URLs don't appear when you view your site.)